# Links in WKWebView randomly not clickable

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

In my iOS app written in Swift 2.1, I use a WKWebView to load a HTML string which is loaded from a wordpress blog using a JSON parser.

I implemented the delegate method `func webView(webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyForNavigationAction navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {` and set the navigation delegate of the WKWebView to self in order to handle link presses.

Now, when I open the ViewController which contains the WKWebView, this delegate method gets called once, which is the behaviour you would expect on load of the webView - so the delegate seems to be set properly.

My problem now is that most time the links which the webView contains are **not clickable**. You would usually expect that a **gray background appears**, when you a press a link as you can see in the image below. But most time, when I press a link, the gray background doesn't appear, so when I touch up, the delegate method doesn't get called. This problem certainly doesn't have to do something with a misconfiguration of the `WKNavigationDelegate`, since sometimes the link selection works properly (about 10 %).

[image: appearance of links when you select them]

Do you have any idea why links are randomly sometimes not clickable, and sometimes clickable (10 % of the cases)?

---

Comment: Would be good if you could show us your html.

Comment: Have you forgot `importing QuartzCore`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to remove the use of `contentInset`. Unfortunately, `WKWebView` isn't designed to handle the use of it (when `contentInset` is negative), so we must use a workaround by simply adding a empty `div` to the htmlString, just like that:

```
<div style='width:100%;height:100px'></div>
```

If the bottom inset should be changed without reloading the entire page, one could at first insert a huge `div` at the bottom and then compensate it by adding a positive `contentInset`. This is exactly what this extension does:

```
extension WKWebView {

   /// The maximum possible height of the webView bottom content inset
   @nonobjc static let maxBottomHeight: CGFloat = 20000

   /// Provides an easy way to set the real bottom inset of the webView. Due to a bug in WKWebView framework, we first insert an emtpy div with the size WKWebView.maxContentSize on the bottom of the webView and compensate it by setting a positive contentInset (should be positive, otherwise the bug will be there again).
   func set(bottomInset inset: CGFloat) {

       self.scrollView.contentInset.bottom = inset - WKWebView.maxBottomHeight
   }
}
```

Don't forget to add the `div` at the end of the html string:

```
let htmlFooter = "<div style='width:100%;height:\(String(describing: WKWebView.maxBottomHeight))px'></div></body></html>"
```

Comment: The issue of links in the contentInsets not being tappable seems to be *finally* solved as of the first betas of Xcode 10 and iOS 12.

Answer (score 2):

I going to suppose that what you want is have some description or text in some place and allow inside some part of the text make clickable/tapped and it's for this that you want to use `WKWebView`.

I solved this problem using `WKWebView` too in some app I made a long time ago, of course there are several solutions, it's just one of them, nothing else.

As some people said to you you can use the `loadHTMLString` function to load the HTML string from your server in JSON or anyway you want, but it's very important that the HTML is good formatted without errors.

A very important point about the `loadHTMLString` function regarding your comment **...You would usually expect that a a gray background appears when you a press a link as you can see in the image below**, it not happen if the HTML don't have some kind of CSS style, because if not it have the default style of any of the `<a><\a>`.

So let's see the following code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

   var wkWebView: WKWebView!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       // The part of the HTMl you want to show
       let description = "Let's start to visit the <a href=\"http://www.apple.com/\">Apple</a> website first and then if you want the <a href=\"http://www.w3schools.com\">Developer Apple</a> website."


       // The default HTML with body and styles formatted and the description inside using string interpolation.
       let htmlString = "<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">body {font-family: \"Lato-Regular\";font-size: 35px;color: #333333;margin: 0;}a {text-decoration: none; color: #999;}</style></head><body>\(description)</body></html>"

       let preferences = WKPreferences()
       preferences.javaScriptEnabled = false

       // Configuration for any preferences you want to set
       let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
       configuration.preferences = preferences

       wkWebView = WKWebView(frame: CGRectMake(5, 35, self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height), configuration: configuration)

       if let theWebView = wkWebView {
          theWebView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: NSURL())
          theWebView.navigationDelegate = self
          self.view.addSubview(theWebView)
       }
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
      // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }

   func webView(webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
      UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
   }


   func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
      UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
   }

   func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: NSError) {
     let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .Alert)
     alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default) { (UIAlertAction) -> Void in
         UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
     })

     presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
}
```

In the above code I set the variable `description` with some text with clickable elements inside it and added the two delegate methods `didStartProvisionalNavigation` and `didFinishNavigation` to show an `networkActivityIndicatorVisible` in the status bars to show the some progress about the loading of the page when the clickable text it's tapped. It's good to notice that in the `htmlString` variable I set some styles to show the `<a>` with some color and font, it's up to you.

I added too the `didFailProvisionalNavigation` function to show an alert in some case the url is not valid of something like the new `HTTPTransportSecurityLayer` added is iOS 9 to only allow **https**, in some cases you can use it to validate the url and know the reason of the error.

The result is the following text in a normal `UIViewController`:

[image]

And when you tap any gray text the **url** would be loaded inside the same `WKWebView`, of course you can personalize this to open in a inside browser you do or something else, it's up to you.

And then you can see the result right away if you tap **Apple**:

[image]

If instead you tap **Developer Apple** you can see the alert in action because the **http** protocol give an error in the `HTTPTransportSecurityLayer` in iOS 9:

[image]

I have the project ready to upload to Github if you need it. I hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I really appreciate it. Unfortunately, it doesn't solve my problem, as I have configured the WKWebView correctly for sure.

Comment: Can you share your project in GitHub?

Comment: return true's answer did the trick, so I don't need further help. Thanks nonetheless!

Answer (score 1):

when you load your content into WKWebView, you might set the wrong baseURL for your webpage, and it leads to invalid link, in order for it working correctly, you should have your baseURL set to the correct http or https URL for your content, for those working link just because they had full url in their href.

here is the html text load into the WKWebView to illustrate the effect:

```
webView.loadHTMLString(content, baseURL: NSURL(string: ""));
```

content:

```
<html lang="en"><head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></head>
    <body>
        <h1> click testing </h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about">Un-Clickable without baseURL</a></li>
            <li><a href="about://about">Clickable without baseURL</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not solving my problem, since I load an html string to the webView, not a website.

Comment: @returnfalse, of course I'm talking about your html string, that's plain html text, do you mind to share the html?

Comment: thanks for answering, but the issue here is, that I can't open links randomly, so sometimes a specific link works, and sometimes not. If it would be an issue with the baseURL, it would always be non-clickable.

Comment: @returnfalse better post a project which you experience the problem, what happens if you long press the non-working link?

Comment: return true's answer did the trick, so I don't need further help. Thanks nonetheless!